# Get MySQL processlist log every 5 seconds

Tags: mysql, linux, database

How can I write a cron job that runs the MySQL "show processlist" command and stores in log file every 5 seconds between 5 am to 7 am?

I know the lowest possible timing I can have in cron is a minute not second. If I need a script, I am looking for a solution in Bash.

I think this cron job works for every 5 minutes between 5 am to 7 am.

```
*/5 5-7 * * * mysql -ufoo --password='' -te "show full processlist" > /home/foo/log/show_processlist.log.`date +\%Y\%m\%d-\%H\%M` 2>&1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write shell/Python/php/something else script which should be run by cron job minutely.

This script should have the following logic (pseudo code):

```
i = 0
while i < 20:
   i++
   show full processlist
   delay 4 sec
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use `mysqladmin` which is MySQL CLI command to administrate database,

> mysqladmin -u root -p -i 5 processlis

Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to stop the running command anytime and use "--verbose" to see the full query.

Answer (score 1):

Set a chron task to run at 05:00 which executes a script that loops over a time value and sleeps for 5 seconds between those time values. May not be exactly 5 seconds as sleep is usually the min time to sleep, but should be close enough.

Comment: upvoted, though I think you mean 5 seconds as the questioneer asked not 5 mins.

Answer (score 0):

Want a bash command on every second to see `FULL` queries?

```
while [ true ]; do mysql -u MYSQLUSERNAME -p'MYSQLUSERPASSWORD' --execute='SHOW FULL processlist;'; sleep 1; done;
```

Assuming you're on a safe environment to enter raw MYSQL password ;).

Comment: can someone please explain why it was marked as -1 without any constructive comments??